# Ignoring undefined properties inside a JSON object when iterating using a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops

I'm using Vanilla JavaScript to iterate through a JSON object. Some properties inside the object are not defined and these are appearing as `undefined` when populated the page with the data.

Is this the best way to iterate through a large data-set using native JavaScript and what am I doing wrong so that the keys that are not defined inside the data-set are ignored?

Also, is forEach the best way or for ... in?

Condensed version of my code below:

```js
/* Sample data:

[{
  "bhp": 354,
  "model": "a45",
  "make": "mercedes"
}, {
  "model": "m4",
  "make": "bmw"
}]

*/ 

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cjhoe');
xhr.onload = function() {
  var cars = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    populate(cars);
  } else {
    console.log('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
  }
};

xhr.send();

function populate(cars) {
  var list = document.getElementById('list');

  cars.forEach(function(car) {
    var carDiv = document.createElement('div');
    carDiv.className = 'car';

    carDiv.innerHTML = '<div>' + car.make + ' </div>';
    carDiv.innerHTML += '<div>' + car.model + ' </div>';
    carDiv.innerHTML += '<div>' + car.bhp + ' </div>';

    list.appendChild(carDiv);
  });
}
```

```css
.car {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.car div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">

</div>
```

Comment: You need to post a sample of your data.

Comment: All you have to do is check each one to see if it is `undefined` and then do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just short circuit each property to an empty string.

```js
/* Sample data:

[{
  "bhp": 354,
  "model": "a45",
  "make": "mercedes"
}, {
  "model": "m4",
  "make": "bmw"
}]

*/ 

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cjhoe');
xhr.onload = function() {
  var cars = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    populate(cars);
  } else {
    console.log('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
  }
};

xhr.send();

function populate(cars) {
  var list = document.getElementById('list');

  cars.forEach(function(car) {
    var carDiv = document.createElement('div');
    carDiv.className = 'car';

    if (car.make) { carDiv.innerHTML = '<div>' + car.make + ' </div>'; }
    if (car.model) { carDiv.innerHTML += '<div>' + car.model + ' </div>'};
    if (car.bhp) { carDiv.innerHTML += '<div>' + car.bhp + ' </div>'; }

    list.appendChild(carDiv);
  });
}
```

```css
.car {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.car div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">

</div>
```

Comment: the issue with this is that it still renders the div in the dom but just empty

Comment: @zxynz I updated my answer to not include the divs, its as simple as using an if statement

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check if the data exists before you do anything with it?

```js
/* Sample data:

[{
  "bhp": 354,
  "model": "a45",
  "make": "mercedes"
}, {
  "model": "m4",
  "make": "bmw"
}]

*/

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cjhoe');
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 200) { // You need this before you parse your JSON
    var cars = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    populate(cars);
  } else {
    console.log('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
  }
};

xhr.send();

function populate(cars) {
  var list = document.getElementById('list');

  cars.forEach(function(car) {
    var carDiv = document.createElement('div');
    carDiv.className = 'car';

    if (car.make) {
      carDiv.innerHTML = '<div>' + car.make + ' </div>';
    }
    if (car.model) {
      carDiv.innerHTML += '<div>' + car.model + ' </div>';
    }
    if (car.bhp) {
      carDiv.innerHTML += '<div>' + car.bhp + ' </div>';
    }

    list.appendChild(carDiv);
  });
}
```

```css
.car {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.car div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">

</div>
```

The only change to your code, is if it exists, add it. Additionally your xhr.status check was in the wrong place.